# How do you change font color of only certain bullets not all

Tags: css, html

I've been having trouble with a certain task.

I have an unordered list, however i want to make the font of the last two in red.
I've figured out how to make them all red, but not only certain ones.

Ive tried this, but the font remains black.

```
<ul>
<li>Website Design</li>
<li>Interactive Animation</li>
<li>E-Commerce Solutions</li>   
<li style=“color:#FF0000”>Usability Studies</li>
<li style=“color:#FF0000”>Search Engine Optimization</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do not use *smart quotes* `“` and `”`, use `"` instead.

Comment: wow that worked, how do i get those quotes instead of the traditional quotes? @Pangloss

Comment: Depending on the text editor you use I guess.

Comment: Also do not share code through skype or similarly awful programs ...

Answer (score 4):

Replace your quotes with regular ones like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Website Design</li>
<li>Interactive Animation</li>
<li>E-Commerce Solutions</li>   
<li style="color:#FF0000">Usability Studies</li>
<li style="color:#FF0000">Search Engine Optimization</li>
</ul>
```

Using a CSS class would be better if you would apply the changes dynamically through JavaScript.

CSS:

```
.special {
   color:#FF0000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="special">Usability Studies</li>
<li class="special">Search Engine Optimization</li>
```

Comment: Using a class would make more sense than inlining several styles.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen I agree, but that is not the question that has been asked here. In some cases, inline styling makes sense. We do not have a context in this particular case, so we are unable to discuss it this time.

Comment: You should also mention that this could be pulled off with `nth-child` and avoid adding to the markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSS it will override the inline style comments. However, if you are not using css, I'd recommend to use css. You would make your list like this in html:

```
<ul>
<li>Website Design</li>
<li>Interactive Animation</li>
<li>E-Commerce Solutions</li>   
<li class="red">Usability Studies</li>
<li class="red">Search Engine Optimization</li>
</ul>
```

and then have your css

```
.red{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Please, avoid repeated `ids`, they should be unique. Use `class` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to learn to how to use CSS, can the CSS be in the same file as my html code?

Comment: `id`'s must be unique across a document, this is invalid HTML. Just use classes instead.

Comment: Sorry using `id`s was a bad idea. The css can be in the same file as your HTML if you put it within `<style> </style>` tags.

Comment: @EliSadoff Inline CSS won't get overridden. It's the other way around. Also, what do you mean exactly by 'using CSS'? CSS is being already used.

Answer (score -1):

remove the style parametr from your tag :

```html
<li color="#FF0000">Usablity Studies</li>
```

Comment: Does that work in your browser? I'm running that code snippet in Chrome on Mac OS X and it doesn't work. Besides that, not using CSS for changing the color doesn't seem valid to me, and don't you need to put a `#` symbol in front of the color?

Comment: Yeah, i edit that, and doesnt work. You are right and sorry for wrong answer.
You should declare it into your CSS.